# Counting the comparisons and swaps in a quick sort

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I am running a quick sort on 2000 integers read from a file but the number of comparisons and swaps i am getting seem high. Are my counters in the right place? or is something wrong with the sort?

```
public int partition(int array[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        int pivot = array[high];  
        int i = (low-1); 
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) 
        {
            compCounter++;
            if (array[j] <= pivot) 
            { 
                i++; 
                int temp = array[i]; 
                array[i] = array[j]; 
                array[j] = temp; 
                SwapCounter++;
            } 
        } 

        int temp = array[i+1]; 
        array[i+1] = array[high]; 
        array[high] = temp; 
        SwapCounter++;

        return i+1; 
    } 

    public void quickSort(int array[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        if (low < high) 
        { 
            int pivotPoint = partition(array, low, high); 
            quickSort(array, low, pivotPoint-1); 
            quickSort(array, pivotPoint+1, high); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: no. I think it is true.

Comment: If your algorithm is O(n) it doesn't mean that you will see exactly n comparisons or swaps or whatever other actions. It means that if your collection size is two times bigger then number of swaps/comparisons will be also two times bigger

Comment: How high are your counters? I'd expect anywhere from 0 to 4000000 with 2000 Ints, but most in the range of ~10000 to ~20000 for compCounter

Answer (score 2):

Your counters are correct.

Just a quick suggestion - move the swap code in a separate function swap(array, fromIndex, toIndex)